# What is the most efficient functional way for refactoring forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I have a method which accepts items and available items from props. While iteration over an array I should filter items by two conditions inside the forEach loop. The first condition is passed item if item id doesn't exist or item id equal 1. The second one should return item and filter 'description' field, otherwise, we push our items into 'nextAvailableItems' array. What is the most efficient functional way for replacing the forEach loop in this situation?

Items structure:

```
[{
  id: 23740416,
  display_name: "test",
  date_from: "1970-12-31"
}]
```

Available items structure:

```
[{
  id: 23740416,
  display_name: "test",
  description: "Text"
}]
```

Expected output:

```
[{
  id: 23740416,
  display_name: "test"
}]
```

Current code:

```
buildAvailableItems() {
  const { items, availableItems } = this.props
  const nextAvailableItems = [...availableItems]

  items.forEach(item => {
    if (!item.id || item.id === -1) {
      return
    }

    const availableItem = availableItems.find(availableItem => availableItem.id === item.id)

    if (availableItem) {
      const { id, display_name } = availableItem

      return { id, display_name }
    }
    const { id, display_name } = item

    nextAvailableItems.push({ id, display_name })
  })

  return nextAvailableItems
}
```

Comment: Note that returning things from a `forEach` doesn't do much... And since you're pushing into a new array, you're probably better off using a combination of `filter` (to remove those with invalid/missing ids) and `map`...

Answer (score 0):

```
buildAvailableItems() {
  const { items, availableItems } = this.props

  const itemIds = items.reduce((c, i) => (c[i.id] = true, c), {})

  const nextAvailableItems = availableItems
    .filter(a => itemIds[a.id])
    .map(a => ({ id: a.id, display_name: a.display_name }))

  return [...availableItems, ...nextAvailableItems]
}
```

First, I would turn `items` into an ID lookup. Then filter your `availableItems` using that lookup. Then do the array merge last.

Comment: it should be `itemIds.includes(...)`

Comment: returns an empty array instead of the expected result, also I guess .filter(i => item.id && item.id !== -1) here item instead of i ?

Comment: note that the available items can be an empty array

Comment: `.filter(i => item.id && item.id !== -1)` mismatched variables `i` and `item`. Use one or the other.

Comment: Also, the lookups would be faster if `itemIds` is a Set.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I guess we don't need itemsIds here at all, cause in the forEach version we just skip items by returning them. I tried sotution like this: 

             `const nextAvailableItems = items`

            `.filter(item => item.id || item.id !== -1 ||` `!availableItems.includes(item.id))`
            `.map(({ id, display_name }) => ({ id, display_name }))`

        `return [...availableItems, ...nextAvailableItems]`

I didn't tested all cases but look likes it works

Comment: `return items`
            `.filter(item => item.id || item.id !== -1 || availableItems[0].id !== item.id).map(({ id, display_name }) => ({ id, display_name }))` . Seems that solution makes sense. Joseph, what do you think?